# How to override admin custom shipping rate?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, admin-panel

How to override admin custom shipping rate like that image attachment? If any extension in magento please share with me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

call ajax on click on that save button and doing below code

```
$quote=Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
$quote->save(); 

$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$price=$address->setShippingAmount+10;

$address->setShippingAmount($price);
$address->setBaseShippingAmount($price);
$address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $price);
$rates = $address->collectShippingRates()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
    foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
        $rate->setPrice($price);
        $rate->save();      
    }
}
$address->setCollectShippingRates(false);
$address->save();
```